# Trigger and stored procedure security in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a database (SQL Server) that is being used by 20 users, all members of the same security role. The role enables them to insert, delete and update to Table1, but they have no permissions for Table2.

Table1 has a trigger that fires a stored procedure, Table2_Refresh, that truncates Table2 and rebuilds it from Table1.

I have read in some places that the trigger and stored procedure automatically execute as the caller, and therefore uses the caller's permissions. However 19 of the 20 users are able to update Table1 and the trigger and SP execute fine. One user gets an error telling him that Table2 cannot be found.

I know I can put an 'EXECUTE AS' line in the SQL, but this is happening in multiple places, and it seems like it is an issue with the user, so I would like to solve it there if possible. Since the role memberships and permissions are identical, are there any other reasons why two users would be experiencing different behaviour from the database?

Answer (score 1):

The role and permissions are *clearly* not identical...

Are they logging in the same way (e.g. are they all using Integrated Security)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check the default schema of the database user used by that special login.
If the table schema is dba but the default schema of the database user is dbo, querying the table without specifying the schema will fail.